# Google sheets | loop through input range in user defined function

Tags: google-sheets

here is a simplified version of my problem:
I want to define a simple custom function that accepts a range of cells as input and returns the SUM of those values. actually I want to learn how to loop through the range inputs. something like the built-in sum of google sheets itself.
How can i do that?

```
function CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(x) {
  //return sum of values in x.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GwOfJFaeYE) guys, I found this solution.

```
function myTester(x) {
  var sum = 0 ;
  if(x && x.length > 0){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
      sum = sum + Number(x[i]) ;
    }
  }
  return sum ;
}
```